# Python Librosa efficient way to get a part from audio that matches condition

Tags: python, audio, librosa, audio-processing

I used librosa module to get this audio file signal, I used this code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
x, sr = librosa.load("./output.wav")
def butter_highpass(data,cutoff, fs, order=5):
    """
    Design a highpass filter.
    Args:
    - cutoff (float) : the cutoff frequency of the filter.
    - fs     (float) : the sampling rate.
    - order    (int) : order of the filter, by default defined to 5.
    """
    # calculate the Nyquist frequency
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    # design filter
    high = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, high, btype='high', analog=False)
    # returns the filter coefficients: numerator and denominator
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y
x_f=butter_highpass(x,1000, sr, order=5)
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.waveshow(x_f, sr=sr)
plt.show()
```

I get this:
[image]

I know python, but I don't have any knowledge of audio processing and this stuff.

Now, Is there a way to get all parts in a long file audio, let's say 1 hour, that have all this intense parts (music).

Comment: By get the part in red, do you mean calculate where the part in red begins and where it ends? If yes, do you know what is distinctive about the sound in that range i.e. what would distinguish it from the bits you want to crop away? Also: your question asks for an efficient way to do this, do you already have an inefficient way to do it?

Comment: I meant by the efficient way is a library that already has a ready function to do that.
I want to calculate the time when the sound gets more intense, like take one second and calculate the average amplitude, if it's above a value, then consider this part as wanted and save these seconds as an array or smth then I can make way to arrange all values and get the whole duration like 20 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:

You can tweak the MIN_VAL until you get your desired result.
The greater the value the script will find parts that have louder volume.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("./m1.wav")
MIN_VAL = 0.1
li = []
li1 = []
max_amp = song.max_dBFS
average = song.dBFS
trigger_dbfs = average - average*MIN_VAL
chunk_length_ms = 5000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(song, chunk_length_ms)
s= 0
start = False
for i in chunks:
    if round(trigger_dbfs,1) <= round(i.dBFS,1):
        if not start:
            start = True

        li.append(i)
    elif start==True:
        li1.append(sum(li, AudioSegment.empty()))
        li = []
        start = False

for i in range(len(li1)):
    li1[i].export(f"audio/{i}.mp3", format="mp3")
a = sum(li1, AudioSegment.empty())
a.export(f"full.mp3", format="mp3")
```

You will have all parts in `song/` directory.
And a full.mp3 in the main directory that will have all the parts in one audio file.

Note: You can also change `chunk_length_ms` value in milliseconds, the value will divide audio by the milliseconds you specify to calculate the volume. If you set a value less than 1 second you will get funky results

Edit: I wrote a repository, you can check it [Bensound-Extract-loud-parts-from-audio](https://github.com/blaze-Youssef/Bensound-Extract-loud-parts-from-audio)

Comment: Just gave the code a whirl and it works for me, too.  You might edit the original question title to be more specific about the condition you are matching to help folks with a similar question find it?  (Also: your code currently assumes the directory "audio" exists)